# passing ArrayList<Item> items to another class

Tags: android, list, android-actionbar, action

I want to add a row to my list: ArrayList items and I used intent. After reseting the adapter in the new class an empty space appeared.
How can I add a row to my list? and how can both classes use the same adapter and list

Comment: Please add your code and xml

Comment: Make use of constructors to pass the list.